# Matlab WindowButtonMotion callback stops working when image is changed

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

In my GUIDE generated gui I have an axes object into which I `imshow()` a bitmap when the gui initializes. I have a WindowButtonMotion callback defined as:

```
function theGui_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  % handles.mode_manager is initialized in the gui startup code
  if (isempty(handles.mode_manager.CurrentMode))
    obj_han=overobj('axes');
    if ~isempty(obj_han)
      set(handles.theGui, 'Pointer','cross');
    else
      set(handles.theGui, 'Pointer','arrow');
    end
  end
end
```

I have a callback on the open file button on the toolbar that does this:

```
function openFile_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  % handles.image_handle received the handle from the imshow that 
  % opened the initial image
  tmp_handle = handles.image_handle;
  [name, path] = uigetfile({'*.bmp'; '*.jpg'});
  if (path == 0)
    return
  else
    filename = strcat(path, name);
  end

  % read the image into the axes panel
  hold on
  handles.image_handle = imshow(filename);
  set(handles.image_handle, 'ButtonDownFcn', @imageMouseDown);
  handles.mode_manager = uigetmodemanager();
  delete(tmp_handle);
  guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

After the new image is displayed in the axes object of the gui, the pointer no longer changes to a cross over the axes object. The problem has something to do with the newly displayed image, because if I comment out the part of the code that actually displays the new image, the pointer appears as a cross after calling the openFile callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback stops working, because using `imshow` replaces the axes object.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
imshow(zeros(100));
h = gca;
h.UserData = 123;  %Set UserData property value to 123
imshow(ones(100)); %Use imshow again.
h2 = gca;
```

Now:

```
h2.UserData

ans =

     []

h.UserData
Invalid or deleted object.
```

As you can see, using `imshow` again replaced the axes object, with new axes object.

---

The following example, modifies only the image data, without modifying the axes:

```
image_handle = imshow(zeros(100));
h = gca;
h.UserData = 123;  %Set UserData property value to 123
%imshow(ones(100), 'Parent', h); %Use imshow again.
image_handle.CData = ones(100); %Modify only image data, without modifying the axes. 
h2 = gca;
```

Now:

```
h2.UserData

ans =

   123
```

---

Modify your `handles.image_handle = imshow(filename);` code to:

```
I = imread(filename);
handles.image_handle.CData = I;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I still don't understand why. The WindowButtonMotion callback is looking to see if the pointer is over *any* axes object, not a specific one. So even though the object was being replaced, the pointer is still over an axes object. 

A followup - how would I read the original image into an axes object created in GUIDE? As the code is currently written, the original axes object is being replaced by the original imshow. (And in spite of this, the WindowButtonMotion callback works at the start.)

Comment: I don't really understand why WindowButtonMotion stop working when replacing the axes... Reading the original image into an axes object: I left it in comment: `imshow(ones(100), 'Parent', h);` (h is an axes, and ones(100) is the image matrix).

Comment: I tried `imshow(filename, 'Parent', axes_handle)` when opening the original image, where axes_handle is the handle GUIDE generates. The axes object is still replaced. But that's more of a bafflement rather than a problem. Thanks